# How to switch to a specific browser tab programmatically using JavaScript with same origin?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using google chrome browser and trying to switch the focus between two browser tabs whose origin is same using JavaScript.

I open a tab say tab_1 using

> `window.open("www.example.com/{data}","_blank");`

And then I open some new tabs say tab_2, tab_3 and tab_4 in the same browser and go back to the first tab tab_1 (**[www.example.com/{data}](http://www.example.com/%7Bdata%7D)**).
Then I do some work on tab_4 and after clicking on the submit button, I close the current tab using window.close() and the focus goes to tab_3 but I want to shift the focus to tab_1 instead.

So, how can I change the focus of the current browser to a specific tab which I opened using window.open() statement?

If it's not possible using Javascript, please help me with any other solution to achieve this.

Comment: Is it a must for new tab to be opened? Can't you redirect user in current tab and use window.history?

Comment: @MahdiarMransouro Yes it is necessary open new  for generating scenario where I can't redirected to destination tab. And no I can't use window.history because it give only current tab states but I need to switch destination tab

Comment: Yes another tab can't hold history of the other one, i don't know how to do that, sorry and good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the window that you open with `window.open()` you have the `window.opener` option, that is the instance that open that tab. But you can't switch between tabs with JavaScript. Wat you can do, after `window.close()`, is reload the current tab to the destination you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use in a button

```
<button onclick="window.close();">Close</button>
```

if you use in function

```
function closeWin() {
  myWindow.close(); 
}
```

But it will only work when you open a window through your code like this

```
function openWin() {
  myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
}
```

You can't close the current window that was open by browser. beacuse browser don't give permission.